# Inserting to SQLite database table does not perserve data after application restart

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an SQLite Database in android application, I am inserting data to a table named Favourite in this database like the following:

```
MySQLiteHelper helper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
                try {
                    helper.createDataBase();
                    helper.openDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                SQLiteDatabase db1 = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put("TypeTitle", genericContents.getTitle());
                contentValues.put("Title", genericContents.getTitle());
                contentValues.put("ModuleID", genericContents.getModuleId());
                contentValues.put("MainImage", genericContents.getMainImage());
                db1.insert("Favourite", null, contentValues);

                try {
                    helper.closeDataBase();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

And my SQLite **helper** is the following:

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "VADEnglish.sqlite";
    public static String DATABASE_PATH = "";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;

    // public static final int DATABASE_VERSION_old = 1;

    // Constructor
    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Vad"+
                 File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
//        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
//            DATABASE_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
//        }
//        else
//        {
//            DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
//        }
        DATABASE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator +"Vad"+File.separator;
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    // Create a empty database on the system
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {


        boolean dbExist1 = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist1) {
            System.out.println("data base are not excist");
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                this.close();
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    // Check database already exist or not
    public boolean checkDataBase() {
        boolean checkDB = false;
        try {
            String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            checkDB = dbfile.exists();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        }
        return checkDB;
    }

    // Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
    // empty database in the system folder
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
        System.out.println("data base upgraded");
    }

    // delete database
    public void db_delete() {
        File file = new File(DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
    }

    public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having,
                        String orderBy) {
        return myDataBase.query("data_table", null, null, null, null, null,
                null);

    }

    public Cursor queryDatabase(String sql) {
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    // Open database
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public synchronized void closeDataBase() throws SQLException {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            try {
              copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("data base couldn't be upgraded");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I can insert to the table with the above code and view its contents in another activity with no troubles at all. However, when I restart the app I found that what I have inserted before I restart the application has gone!

I am reading table contents like the following:

```
final MySQLiteHelper helper = new MySQLiteHelper(FavoriteList.this);
        try {
            helper.createDataBase();
            helper.openDataBase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SQLiteDatabase db1 = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor c = db1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Favourite", null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
                FavoriteListItemModel fav = new FavoriteListItemModel();

                fav.setType(c.getString(0));
                fav.setTitle(c.getString(1));
                fav.setModule(c.getString(2));
                fav.setImg(c.getString(3));

                my_list.add(fav);

                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }

        try {
            helper.closeDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Anybody can help me with this?

Comment: where are you creating the table?

Comment: It's in the SQLite file in assets folder in the application, I can view it using DB Browser for SQLite.